# How to use correctly the pdo in php application?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would know what is better for an application using pdo in php on the result and application speed.

```
  $Qcountries = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('select countries_id,
                                        countries_name 
                                        from :table_countries
                                        where countries_iso_code_2 = :countries_iso_code_2 
                                        limit 1');
          $Qcountries->bindValue(':countries_iso_code_2', $country );
          $Qcountries->execute();

          $countries = $Qcountries->fetch();

          $country_name = $countries['countries_name'];

          echo $country_name;
```

or

```
  $Qcountries = $OSCOM_PDO->prepare('select countries_id,
                                        countries_name 
                                        from :table_countries
                                        where countries_iso_code_2 = :countries_iso_code_2 
                                        limit 1');
          $Qcountries->bindValue(':countries_iso_code_2', $country );
          $Qcountries->execute();

          echo $Qcountries->value('countries_name');
```

Comment: Both examples will fail equally fast since you have an error - you have 2 parameters specified, only 1 bound. You can't bind table name via parameters. Also, it looks like you're asking whether it's quicker to use array index or method `value()`. I don't see `value` method anywhere in `PDOStatement` in the manual. Array index call is quicker than a method call. If your example is remade into working one, array index call is faster but in the grand scheme of things - it's irrelevantly faster.

Comment: The request work fine, no problem. If I understand what you said, it's better to do that : echo $Qcountries->value('countries_name'); than to do echo $country_name; It' faster.